# Conditionally closing tag in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, conditional-statements, thymeleaf

I need to conditionally close tag in my `Thymeleaf` template. Say, during iterating some collection of elements I have to wrap series of some of them into single `<div>`:

```
<div>...element1, element2, element3...</div>
<div>...element4...</div>
<div>...element5, element6...</div>
```

This could be archived if some way of conditionally tag closing would exist. But I can't obviously write `</div th:if="...">`. If it would be `jsp` I could easily write something like:

```
<%if (condition) {%></div><%}%>
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

**EDIT** To be precise, my *elements* aren't just strings, they are complex inner html blocks.

Comment: I think you need to wrap the `<div> elem1,2,3 </div>` in the condition using `th:if` and `th:unless` blocks.(If that's what you are asking) But doesn't thymeleaf throw an error if the closing tag is missing? Why would you need this for?

Comment: @Lucky please, If I ask, then I need it definitely .

Comment: But this wouldn't run I guess. So thats why I asked it. You could try the if, unless blocks. Because when I ran into the same issue. Thymleaf dint allow half baked html code. It throwed error if the element has no close block. Or may be switch statement if needed.

Comment: @Lucky that was the question. It is obvious that `Thymeleaf` doesn't allow it. But I've found the solution, you can find it below (besides one man, I know who, downvoted it for revenge).

Comment: @Lucky No, I don't think that it was you. It was one of the answerers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the workaround. Series of blocks which should be wrapped into single `<div>` should be represented as separated lists inside model. Say, it I have `Element` class which describes my `element` block. So, my model should be like:

`List<Element> elementGroups`

and I have to create double loop for it:

```
<div th:each="group : ${elementGroups}">
    <th:block th:each="element : ${group}">
       ...
    </th:block>
</div>
```

Comment: IMHO this is not an answer to the problem. Of course you can do this. But it's not always practical to group the list on the controller level. I think this is usually a view concern and better to be done in the view (template) level. ps. I am not the downwoter and won't downvote your answer to your own question, but if I were you I'd accept Tobias's answer instead of this.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's better represent the data as separate lists, as you mentioned in [your previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36770126/3963330).

But even for curiosity, there is an ugly workaround to achieve something similar to `<%if (condition) {%></div><%}%>`, as you asked.

The trick is to generate the tag as escaped text:

```
<th:block th:if="${openTagCondition}" th:utext="'&lt;div&gt;'" /> 

<th:block th:if="${colseTagCondition}" th:utext="'&lt;/div&gt;'" />
```

This is just out of curiosity. I do not recommend using this workaround as it's pretty unreadable, harms maintainability and you can leave unbalanced tags.

Comment: Thanks, this was the cleanest solution I've found. I have a list, and depending on various conditions I have to group elements in this list into wrapping divs. I don't have the information for wrapping in the controller. It's totally a view (template) related thing in my case. I understand that this low level html manipulation is not nice, but I haven't found other solutions!

Answer (score -2):

move the conditional logic up one layer

```
<body th:each="...">
    <div></div>
</body>
```

take a look at the documentation here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean? How this will solve my issue?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12097758)

Comment: maybe you could clarify the question and show us some code. so we can better answer your question

Comment: @pczeus how does it not answer the question. I'm showing him how to loop through a collection, and providing direct documentation on looping. Maybe his answer should be more clear on what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: Posting code only without a good explanation of how it helps and solves the OP's issue is not considered a good answer. Just provide a bit more explanation of how this solves the problem. For more info, please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Dear @ndrone I'm not asking *how to loop through a collection*. Read question more attentive. The question about *how conditionally close tag*. The answer of sanluck is much closer to the sense.

Comment: you can't thymeleaf doesn't work that way. It's a templating engine that follows strict HTML5 standards. The best you can do is wrap each element of the collection in it's own div.

Comment: You are wrong triply. First one - you didn't understand the essence of the question and posted some kind of useless thing. Second one - you think that the question relates to HTML5 some how. It doesn't. And at least, third one - I've found the decision and posted it here.