# Can these IntelliJ warnings about my Thymeleaf template be avoided?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I have a straight-forward Thymeleaf template that produces the desired output. However IntelliJ's analysis of the template is reporting two warnings that are not strictly correct (although I can understand why they are generated). I'd like to know if the warnings can be prevented by structuring the template differently or giving some hint to IntelliJ.

Here's the relevant snippet from my template. Essentially I'm iterating over a list of objects that are grouped according to the `group` attribute. For each group I wish to insert a heading and unordered list tag before the objects in that group and append a closing tag afterwards. The fact that the opening and closing tags are not clearly tied together is causing the two warnings (indicated by the comments (1) and (2) in the code) to occur.

```
<!--/*@thymesVar id="issues" type="java.util.List<com.example.Issue>"*/-->
<th:block th:each="issue,i : ${issues}">
  <th:block th:if="${i.first || !issue.uniqueName.equals(issues.get(i.index - 1).uniqueName)}">
    <h3 th:text="${issue.group.name}"></h3>
    <ul> <!-- (1) Element ul is not closed -->
  </th:block>
  <li class="warning" th:text="${issue.name + ': ' + issue.message}"></li>
  <th:block th:if="${i.last || !issue.uniqueName.equals(issues.get(i.index + 1).uniqueName)}">
    </ul>  <!-- (2) Closing tag matches nothing -->
  </th:block>
</th:block>
```

Here's some sample output which makes it clear that the generated HTML is indeed correct, ie. the `ul` tag is opened and closed correctly.

```
<h3>Group 1</h3>
<ul>
   <li class="warning">Sample 1: message 1</li>
   <li class="warning">Sample 2: message 2</li>
</ul>
<h3>Group 2</h3>
<ul>
   <li class="warning">Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet</li>
   <li class="warning">Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

So is there a way to avoid these IntelliJ warnings about an element not being closed and a closing tag matching nothing?

Comment: (Common for IDEA and other JetBrains IDE) Alt + Enter on the warning source, hover on the specified warning, is there a "Disable this warning" selection?

Comment: If you want to suppress the warnings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html. If you think it's a bug that should be fixed, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: IntelliJ's suggested solution (via Alt Enter) is simply to remove the tag. I wasn't able to find a way to suppress these warnings.

Comment: There is no way of doing this unless you disable warnings for the IDE. IntelliJ simply treats this as an unclosed tag in the current context.

Comment: Is that the exact HTML you used to arrive at that output?  I don't see the hyphen in the `<h3>` tag.

Comment: @bphilipnyc Good point. In converting my actual code and output to an MVCE, I've left that behind. I'll fix my question accordingly. Importantly, it makes no difference w.r.t. my actual issue.

Comment: Sure.  My thinking is that there may be another way to write the HTML, but I'd find it tough to restructure it if I don't have the exact requirements down.

Comment: Fair enough. I couldn't see a way to restructure the HTML, but I'd love to know if it's possible. (Thinking about it, I could convert the issues to `List<List<Issue>>` with one sub-list per group which would make the template easier to write. But I'm more interested in the warnings.)

Comment: Is it viable to add a set or list of issue groups to the model instead of a list of issues?  That way, you can iterate over each group and then each issue in that group.  The HTML becomes a lot cleaner, as does the intent of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I could probably do that as I control the model and the view. In the more general case, where the model is fixed, can the view (template) be done without warnings?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but if you *must*, you could explore trying something like this for your `<ul>` tag.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747620/conditionally-closing-tag-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

Currently, IntellijIDEA allows for adding `th:block` to its list of custom HTML tags. This is only partially satisfactory, as it then will not mark it as wrong if you use it outside of Thymeleaf.

Granted, this is a corner case, but it's a corner case I run into a lot since one domain may use Thymeleaf, another Freemarker, and then there are those pesky Twig templates that some PHP project is serving up. It increases the risk of me using the wrong syntax out of habit.